# php set my own timezone based on given GMT offset

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I've my GMT offset in seconds. I would like to `set_default_time_zone()` to that GMT offset. What I mean that if I have my GMT offset to 2 hours(7200 seconds) it will set the timezone to GMT+2 if I have 3 hours(10800 seconds) it will set the timezone to GMT+3, how can I do that? the `set_default_time_zone()` only accept pre-defined timezones strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GMT offsets, but you must use the `Etc` prefix. The following works:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+5');
```

But this is discouraged an deprecated, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Also, I personally would recommend not to work with offsets, because there are many pitfalls in date/time handling where GMT offsets can cause bad results (e.g. DST, first day of the week).

It is generally recommended to work with UTC internally, and set local times to the geographical timezone instead of the GMT offset.

Comment: well, the user in my application decides the DST dates. Therefore the times are either +2 or +3. Doesn't matter if it's UTC+2 or GMT+2. I really need to be flexible here. What would you recommend to do then?

Comment: I would recommend to let users only pick their location-based timezone. Everything else can be handled internally. PHP's `DateTime` and friends do a fine job handling all the dirty work. Or is there a reason why people should manually set their DST settings in your application?

Comment: @kfirba - Keep in mind that the sign of these zones are inverted.  +2 is actually `"Etc/GMT-2"`.  But lxg is absolutely correct that using these are discouraged.  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for rationale and further details.